# Regex help - match to number or end of string

Tags: regex

Struggling to work this one out as I'm not great with regex. I have strings like this:

```
Method
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pro lorem consulatu, ut nemore principes vel. Nibh aliquam iracundia ea est, probo utamur placerat at duo. Nam an perfecto voluptaria temporibus, no dicat dolores eum. Doming dissentias eloquentiam sit id, sit eu etiam scriptorem appellantur, ne explicari voluptaria nec.

Agam erroribus cum id, vis ei nominavi copiosae. Per unum atomorum ut, amet atqui moderatius in mel, ex mucius concludaturque vix. Ei quodsi admodum conclusionemque duo, pro vidit nonumy fastidii at. Aliquip voluptua appetere eam id.
42
Aliquip voluptua appetere
```

Which I can detect fine with the following regex: `/^Method\n(.*[\s\S]*)(?:\d\d)/`

https://regex101.com/r/Uw3XzK/1

The problem comes in occassionally the string I am detecting does not end in a number. Here I generally just need to go to the end of the string.

```
Method
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pro lorem consulatu, ut nemore principes vel. Nibh aliquam iracundia ea est, probo utamur placerat at duo. Nam an perfecto voluptaria temporibus, no dicat dolores eum. Doming dissentias eloquentiam sit id, sit eu etiam scriptorem appellantur, ne explicari voluptaria nec.

Agam erroribus cum id, vis ei nominavi copiosae. Per unum atomorum ut, amet atqui moderatius in mel, ex mucius concludaturque vix. Ei quodsi admodum conclusionemque duo, pro vidit nonumy fastidii at. Aliquip voluptua appetere eam id.
```

I have tried adding a `?` to the stirng. `/^Method\n(.[\s\S])(?:\d\d)?` however this then breaks the matching of the first string.

What can I do to first and foremost match string 1, but then fall back to matching to the end of the file?

Comment: What programming language are you using (if any) ?

Comment: *"Here I generally just need to go to the end of the string."* then... *"... but then fall back to matching to the end of the file?"* So is it end of string as in new line or end of file if the number is not present?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen PHP , but looking for a regex solution for the match rather than switching regex patterns

Comment: @zer00ne the end of file if number is not present

Comment: @RobertOwen Your current pattern, slightly modified, can be made to work with PHP.

Comment: @RobertOwen `/^Method\n(([\s\S]+)(?:\d\d)|([\s\S]+))/gm` The `|` is an OR gate so it'll match everything between literal `Method` newline and 2 digits OR it'll match everything after literal `Method` newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern in fact works with PHP, when using `preg_match_all` in dot all mode:

```
\bMethod.*?(?=\d{2}|$)
```

Sample script:

```
$input = "Method\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pro lorem consulatu, ut nemore principes vel. Nibh aliquam iracundia ea est, probo utamur placerat at duo. Nam an perfecto voluptaria temporibus, no dicat dolores eum. Doming dissentias eloquentiam sit id, sit eu etiam scriptorem appellantur, ne explicari voluptaria nec.\nAgam erroribus cum id, vis ei nominavi copiosae. Per unum atomorum ut, amet atqui moderatius in mel, ex mucius concludaturque vix. Ei quodsi admodum conclusionemque duo, pro vidit nonumy fastidii at. Aliquip voluptua appetere eam id.\n42\nAliquip voluptua appetere";
preg_match_all("/\bMethod.*?(?=\d{2}|$)/s", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Hi, tried this, but it will go to the end of the file all the time rather than stop at the number if the number is present

Comment: @RobertOwen Not true at all.  [See this demo](https://rextester.com/HQBA77651).  You need to test against PHP; a regex demo site is not reflective of reality all the time.

Comment: Hi Tim, I was testing in PHP too... however if you notice in my first example I had the text after 'Method' grouped. My preg_match was returning $match[1] as null but I had overlooked that group 1 had been removed from the regex.

Apologies!

Comment: Also if you check my reply example https://regex101.com/r/l5NvoS/2 the .* is grouped, but the ? is outside of the bracket. Moving it inside the bracket solved the problem